# Gatsby, GraphQL & Apollo caching issue

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, gatsby, apollo

I've just rebuilt a new portfolio site using Gatsby, which dynamically displays my projects, using Apollo and GraphQL.

I'm really happy with the performance, however I've noticed that the project items page will sometimes show the previously loaded content for a split second before displaying the correct content.

My approach was based on this demo - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNUg1jpj9T0&t=18m01s

Does anyone know how I prevent this issue from happening please?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is your content fully dynamic (client-side queries with Apollo), or are you also sourcing it on build with Gatsby? There could be a delay (networking time) between your static site's paint and the resolving of your client-side data fetching. The tutorial you pointed to ([repo](https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo)) showcases the same thing, with a parallel server-side and client-side query

Comment: Thanks Robin! The content is fully dynamic. However, the problem was actually far more basic in the end. I return a variable containing all the new content. I simply needed to reset this variable prior to the new data being loaded. This prevented the previous content from being returned :) Thanks for your help! Paul